# How to archive all completed tasks under a headline?

Tags: org-mode

I've got an org file that looks like this:

```
* Project Cats
** Get them
*** TODO Find a tabby
*** DONE Find one that's orange
    CLOSED: [2016-11-08 Tue 15:32]
** Feed them
*** DONE Buy some food
    CLOSED: [2016-11-08 Tue 15:32]
*** TODO Put it in bowls
```

Is there a command that, with my cursor on the top headline, will archive everything marked as DONE that's a descendant? After running such a command, I'd expect to see this:

```
* Project Cats
** Get them
*** TODO Find a tabby
** Feed them
*** TODO Put it in bowls
```

Comment: The doc-string for `org-archive-subtree` states the options that are presently available -- `M-x describe-function RET org-archive-subtree RET`  In particular, read about the prefix argument and see if that achieves the desired result.

Comment: @lawlist the prefix arguments to `org-archive-subtree` will examine only the direct children of the headline, and they will archive a child only if all tasks it contains are done. (Or all timestamps are in the past.) I want to examine anything that's a descendant of the headline, and I want to archive individual items marked as done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a single command, but the following sequence accomplishes this:

1. `C-c a` to look at the agenda
2. `< <` to restrict the agenda to the buffer and then to the current sub-tree
3. `M DONE` to show everything matching a TODO keyword (search for `DONE` items in the current sub-tree)
4. `*` to mark everything in the agenda (all `DONE` items in the current subtree).
5. `B $` to bulk archive everything you marked (i.e. everything)

Comment: Any insight into why there isn't a standard command to do this? I'm still learning org-mode and this seemed like a natural thing to do.

Comment: @DGrady Just guessing, but probably nobody asked for it.  There are so many ways to use `org-mode` that they can't account for all of them.  So instead they provide basic building blocks: agendas, filters, bulk actions.  You can put those together into anything you need.

Answer (score 2):

On my e-macs using iTerm2 and macOS it is not exactly the same sequence to **archive** all the done tasks (in a whole given doc):

- `C-c a` to display the agenda
- `T DONE` to match all entries with the keyword DONE
- `*` to mark them all
- `B $` to archive

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Robert's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71374607/15821022)

```lisp
(require 'org)
(require 'org-archive)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-archive-all-done nil t)))
```

Comment: FWIW: It's generally better not to use anonymous functions (lambdas) on hooks. A named function is easier to remove, for example. Function comparison is problematic; symbol comparison is not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm noob and learning everyday about emacs and lisp, I didn't knew this, feel free to edit the answer with a named function.